# kotlin null safe container' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time

Tags: kotlin

```
class ExchangeRatesServiceImpl : ExchangeRatesService {

    private var container: ExchangeRatesContainer? = null

    /**
     * {@inheritDoc}
     */
    override val currentRates: Map<Currency, BigDecimal>
        get() {
            if (container == null || container.date != LocalDate.now()) {
                container = client.getRates(Currency.getBase())
                        log.info("exchange rates has been updated: {}", container)
            }
            return ImmutableMap.of<Currency, BigDecimal>(
                    Currency.EUR, container.rates[Currency.EUR.name],
                    Currency.RUB, container.rates[Currency.RUB.name],
                    Currency.USD, BigDecimal.ONE
            )
        }
}
```

line if (container == null || container.date != LocalDate.now())
error 【because 'container' is a mutable property that could have been changed by this time】

How can I compile it?

Answer (score 2):

`container` is declared outside of the scope of the function, so another thread could theoretically modify it between you checking for `null` and then using it. To prevent this, you should create a local variable initialized to `container`, and use it like so:

```
class ExchangeRatesServiceImpl : ExchangeRatesService {

private var container: ExchangeRatesContainer? = null

/**
 * {@inheritDoc}
 */
override val currentRates: Map<Currency, BigDecimal>
    get() {
        val tempContainer = container
        if (tempContainer == null || tempContainer.date != LocalDate.now()) {
            tempContainer = client.getRates(Currency.getBase())
                    log.info("exchange rates has been updated: {}", tempContainer)
        }
        return ImmutableMap.of<Currency, BigDecimal>(
                Currency.EUR, container.rates[Currency.EUR.name],
                Currency.RUB, container.rates[Currency.RUB.name],
                Currency.USD, BigDecimal.ONE
        )
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

As apemanzilla already mentioned, this is a threading issue. Kotlin prevents you from doing that, even if you have just one thread, because there is a chance another thread tries accessing it. It's basically a race; even if you check if it isn't null, there's a theoretical chance it could be null a millisecond later, when the next calls are made.

However, there are multiple solutions to this. And I do want to point out a flaw with apemanzilla's code: it does not set the outer container. Which means `tempContainer == null` is always true. The main problem with using a temp variable like that is that it always ends up requiring two calls. Also, the temp variable needs to be a variable. Otherwise you can't set it. It'll just say "val cannot be reassigned".

Now, for the actual solution:

The first one (I do not recommend this), is using null assertion. ***Only*** do this if you can guarantee it's not modified by other threads, or it will crash your program:

```
return ImmutableMap.of<Currency, BigDecimal>(
        Currency.EUR, container!!.rates[Currency.EUR.name],
        Currency.RUB, container!!.rates[Currency.RUB.name],
        Currency.USD, BigDecimal.ONE
)
```

You also have to do the same here:

```
if (container == null || container!!.date != LocalDate.now()) { ... }
```

Though using null-safe is actually better. Null comparing with non-null is fine. Just like `if(null != "some string")` (this is always true, but you get the idea):

```
if (container == null || container?.date != LocalDate.now) { ... }
```

You can also use null-safe with the elvis operator if you feel like it:

```
return ImmutableMap.of<Currency, BigDecimal>(
        Currency.EUR, container?.rates[Currency.EUR.name] ?: TODO(),
        Currency.RUB, container?.rates[Currency.RUB.name] ?: TODO(),
        Currency.USD, BigDecimal.ONE
)
```

Alternatively, you can use let:

```
container?.let { /* it -> is explicitly declared here */
    return ImmutableMap.of<Currency, BigDecimal>(
        Currency.EUR, it.rates[Currency.EUR.name], // You might still need the elvis operator on these if it.rates[something] can return null
        Currency.RUB, it.rates[Currency.RUB.name],
        Currency.USD, BigDecimal.ONE
    )
}
```

Although this makes it slightly harder to deal with the if-statement.

***However***, this requires you to add a second return. If container is null, it will not execute that code, which means you need a final `return` statement. You could try recursively re-calling the code until you succeed, return default values, throw an exception, return null, whatever you feel like.

And the final is, as apemanzilla mentioned, temporary variables.

This creates a local variable, which is locally immutable, which means you don't get problems with nullability.

```
val currentRates: Map<Currency, BigDecimal>
    get() {
        var localContainer = container // This needs to be a var; you assign it, then re-assign it. You can't do that with a `val`
        if (localContainer == null || localContainer.date != LocalDate.now()) {

            localContainer = client.getRates(Currency.getBase())
            log.info("exchange rates has been updated: {}", tempContainer)
            container = localContainer // This is also necessary to prevent it from always updating. 
        }

        return ImmutableMap.of<Currency, BigDecimal>(
                Currency.EUR, container.rates[Currency.EUR.name],
                Currency.RUB, container.rates[Currency.RUB.name],
                Currency.USD, BigDecimal.ONE
        )
    }
```

Though, to be honest, I don't understand *why* you check `container.date != LocalDate.now()`. This is always true if the time doesn't match. So if I've understood your code correctly, you can just shorten it to:

```
val currentRates: Map<Currency, BigDecimal>
    get() {
        val localContainer = client.getRates(Currency.getBase())
        // container = localContainer // If you use the container somewhere else. 
        log.info("exchange rates has been updated: {}", tempContainer)

        return ImmutableMap.of<Currency, BigDecimal>(
                Currency.EUR, container.rates[Currency.EUR.name],
                Currency.RUB, container.rates[Currency.RUB.name],
                Currency.USD, BigDecimal.ONE
        )
    }
```